# Clone jQuery selection into variable and insert it back into DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, clone

What am i doing wrong, isn't it possible to clone elements into a variable and insert it back into DOM from there?

```
var clonedElements = $('.source .item').clone();
$('.target .item').each(function(index) {
    $(this).after(clonedElements[0]);
});
```

Decrease the cloned array by always inserting the first element after a element extisting in target.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/yg76uhnk

Comment: Sorry, just edited my example...

Comment: Two things.  #1) `$('.source .item').clone;` is missing the `()` to invoke clone.  #2) When you append existing dom elements to another parent, it moves them from their original place, as elements can only exist under a single parent.  If you want to put them in multiple places, you will need a clone for each occurance.

Comment: Sorry, missed the brackets, edited. Yes, inserting the "first" ([0]) from the array is meant that after each insert, the next element can be accessed by [0]... But still, why does the second exaple not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my mistake:

```
$(this).after(clonedElements[0]);
```

...doens't remove the element from array and the next elements don't get a new index to be accessable by [0] again, like they would when acting on a jQuery object:

```
$(this).after($('.source .item')[0]);
```

So the solution is to convert the clones to an array and shift on them:

```
var items = $(".source .item").clone().toArray();
$('.target .item').each(function(index) {
    $(this).after(items.shift());                
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9q6brnkv/

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `after()` the cloned element, and it will put it after the element.  If there are more than one elements that you are inserting elements after, it will perform additional clones as part of the `after()` logic.

```js
$('.target .item').after($('.source .item').clone());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="source" style="display:none;">
  <div class="item">New Source</div>
</div>

<div class="target">
  <div class="item">Original Target</div>
  <div class="item">Original Target</div>
  <div class="item">Original Target</div>
  <div class="item">Original Target</div>
  <div class="item">Original Target</div>
</div>
```